# When I recreate an Account using a Mnemonic, will it also bring back its private key?

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, accounts, keystore

I guess my Question is straight-forward, I would like to know if using a **Mnemonic** to recreate or *import* an Ethereum (external) Account will actually make or "bring back" the whole KeyPair (public **and** private keys)?

Or, just the public Key (address)?

Regards,

-Jose

Comment: when you recreate? Was this something you deleted before and are now trying to create again? Or do you mean create a second account, which would be duplicating and not recreating?

Answer (score 2):

Your 12 word mnemonic can always be used to regenerate your addresses and public keys and private keys.

The 12 word mnemonic is the ultimate power for everything that is going on in your Ethereum account.

Comment: Note that often a additional password is required to generate all the keys. You can leave that blank, but since the tuple (mnemonic, password) is used to generate your keys, leaving the password blank leads to the generation of the same keys for identical mnemonics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 12 word mnemonics can be used to generate all of the pub/private key-pairs generated from it originally.

You can also use it across multiple crypto wallets / coins that use mnemonic key generating. Idk if I'd do that but you can.

**Pros**: You only have to memorize one mnemonic

**Con**: if that one gets compromised some how you lose all your other assets.